# mailto insert a link as the body

Tags: c#, html, mailto

I'm trying to insert a link into the body of an email:

> string.Format("mailto:email@address.com?subject{0}&body{1}", "Subject
>   Message",
>   "Http://hostname/default.aspx?id={0000000-00000-0000-00000000000)&language=en");

My issue is that the link stops before { and the complete link is not clickable.

I have tried to replace { by %7B and } by %7D but it's not working.
Do you have any idea on how to implement that kind of URL ?

Thank you

Comment: Is the BodyFormat Html? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat.aspx

Comment: I have tried with Request.Url.AbsoluteURI. The complete URL is correctly defined in the source code (confirmed with View source) but when I m clicking on the link, the URL is not correctly shown on the Outlook Message body.

Comment: I'm using mailto, to open my client email. I don't want to send directly the email. How can we define the mail format with <a href="mailto:email@address.com ....." ?

Comment: So you're not programatically generating the email? You have a hyperlink when clicked is opening whatever email client the user has?

Comment: In your example closing GUID bracket is not curly. Is this a typo?

Comment: GUID bracket is indeed a typo error.

Comment: My goal is indeed to click on a link and open the client email of the user to insert a link of the current page. He will share the page with another user. The reader will be able to select the TO himself

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following as your body (i.e. replacing special characters with hex codes - see http://www.ascii-code.com/ for reference)

```
Http://hostname/default.aspx%3Fid=%7B0000000-00000-0000-00000000000%7D%26language=en
```

You mentioned you'd tried this with the brackets - but did you also do the ampersand and question mark?

ps. you're also missing the equals signs from your code.  Full code should be:

```
string.Format("mailto:email@address.com?subject={0}&body={1}", "Subject Message", "Http://hostname/default.aspx%3Fid=%7B0000000-00000-0000-00000000000%7D%26language=en");
```

Sample stand alone HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="mailto:person@host.com?subject=test&body=http://hostname/default.aspx%3Fid=%7B0000000-00000-0000-00000000000%7D%26language=en">test</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the ? and &. After replacing those characters, it's still not working. The link "clickable" stop after id= and just before {

Comment: I assume the c# code sends its output to a web page, which is where you click the link from.  If you view the source of the generated web page is the link as you'd expect (i.e. to trace down whether there's a fault somewhere in the content generation) - as the above works for me if I create a static html page and click the link (opening with Outlook 2010 as default client).

Comment: Ahh - in fact I've just realised your meaning - you do get the full text, it's just only the first part of the text is converted to a hyper link - I'd misunderstood - investigating now.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `%7B0000000-00000-0000-00000000000%7D` with `%257B0000000-00000-0000-00000000000%257D`?  See http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy

Comment: I don't see the difference. Do I should see %257 in my HTML Code ? Because i can only see %7b and %7d. And i made a refresh, cleaning of the cache. There is no change.

Comment: The idea is that when written to the HTML page `%257B` is written as is.  When the link is clicked this resolves to `%7B` in the URL (instead of `{`) and thus the link is not terminated at the `{` but goes all the way to the end.  When you then click this URL the web server should interprit `%7B` exactly as it would `{`. . . I think.